# Why am I getting this error? It seems that I have an error in s1.grade_level but I do not know why

Tags: java, class, object

Student Class file

I used primitive and reference variable type for my student class.

```
public class Student {
    int id_number;
    String student_name;
    String dob;
    int grade_level;
   }
```

App.java file

I created one student object and stored user input.

```
   import java.util.Scanner;

 public class App {

public static void main( String[] args ) {
    
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String[] infoArray = {"ID Number: ", "Student Name: ", "Date Of Birth: ", "Grade Level: "}; 
    System.out.println("Please provide information below.");
    System.out.println(infoArray[0] +"\n" + infoArray[1]+"\n"+ "i.e 02/06/1981\n" + infoArray[2] +"\n"+ infoArray[3]);
    
    
    Student s1 = new Student();
    s1.id_number = sc.nextInt();
    s1.student_name = sc.nextLine();
    s1.dob = sc.nextLine();
    s1.grade_level = sc.nextInt();
    
    System.out.println( infoArray[0] +  s1.id_number + "\n" + infoArray[1] +  s1.student_name + "\n" +  "i.e 02/06/1981");
    System.out.println( infoArray[2] + s1.dob + "\n"+ infoArray[3] + s1.grade_level);
    
    }

}
```

Output:

I'm not really sure why it gives me an error when I press enter right after I input the Date of Birth. I'm new to classes and objects so I would appreciate if someone explained to me what I did wrong.

```
         Please provide information below.
         ID Number: 
         Student Name: 
         i.e 02/06/1981
         Date Of Birth: 
         Grade Level: 
         98746532
         John Doe
         09/30/1938
         Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
              at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:864)
              at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
              at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)
              at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this and check,

```
    s1.id_number = sc.nextInt();
    sc.nextLine(); // add this
    s1.student_name = sc.nextLine();
```

Comment: refer this for explanation https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-or-nextfoo